# PL/SQL: Inserting the values of a column of a table into an array or VARRAY to be accessed by java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, callable-statement

I need to take the values from a specific column in a table and place them into an array.
I'm thinking to use a PL/SQL Stored procedure then calling the procedure in java and using something like:

```
    CallableStatement.getArray(2, myArray);
```

I  was thinking of using something like:

```
SELECT column1 
INTO myVARRAY
FROM table1
WHERE table_id = t_id;
```

In a stored procedure
But that didn't work

Comment: "But that didn't work".  C'mon, give us a clue.  How didn't it work?  We are not telepathic, so you need to provide details: describe the observed behaviour, results, error messages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presume that `myVARRAY` is of type `varchar2`. In this case you could try something like

```
p_col   VARCHAR2 (32);

SELECT column1 
INTO p_col
FROM table1
WHERE table_id = t_id;
```

and then you add p_col into your array by

```
myVARRAY.EXTEND;
myVARRAY (1) := p_col;

RETURN myVARRAY;
```

And from Java call your array by

```
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "MYVARRAY");
```

Hope this will be helpful, otherwise provide more information about your function/procedure and the type of errors you are getting.